# Delete statement after executing a SQL insert twice

Tags: sql, oracle

From an Oracle database, I have executed an insert SQL statement twice in a production environment.

Sadly, the rollback option did not seem to work.

The insert statement was:

```
INSERT INTO MAE_INT.T_INT_APPLICATION (INAP_IDENT, INAP_PARAM, INAP_VALEUR, INAP_DATE) 
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(INAP_IDENT)+1 FROM MAE_INT.T_INT_APPLICATION), 'monitoring', 'true', '10/06/2016');

COMMIT;
```

I guess the only option now is to make a delete statement for the double.

Anyone can help with that? Not sure how to write it

Comment: That select query will return only 1 row because of aggregate function. look for that last inserted row and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete `max(INAP_IDENT)` like below, thereby leaving you with first `insert` statement only.

**NOTE: TEST IT IN DEV/UAT ENVIRONMENT FIRST**

```
delete from MAE_INT.T_INT_APPLICATION
where INAP_IDENT=
 (SELECT MAX(INAP_IDENT) FROM MAE_INT.T_INT_APPLICATION);
```

Before committing, check if you dont have duplicate entry.

Comment: Thanks i will check it first. 
@utsav : how to check for duplicate entry ? select statement?

Comment: First find the `max(INAP_IDENT)`. Note it. Lets say it is `123`. Now search for `INAP_IDENT in (123,124)`. If you see the 2 entries that you inserted, then you can proceed. Once you run delete, check if max entry is deleted and other one is intact.

Comment: If it is deleted, check then run, `select * from MAE_INT.T_INT_APPLICATION
where INAP_IDENT=
 (SELECT MAX(INAP_IDENT) FROM MAE_INT.T_INT_APPLICATION);` and make sure that first entry is still there. If you are satisfied, then only commit.

Comment: If it worked, then accept the answer so the question could be closed.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thanks !